# Socket.io emit doesn't work but broadcast is fine

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm trying to emit a notification to a single client but the emit does not seems to fire at all whereas broadcast.emit works fine. But the problem is broadcast is notifying all clients even if I supply the socket.id.

Anyone have any idea what I did wrong?

```
var app = express( );
var querystring = require('querystring');
var server  = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var clients = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function( socket ) {
    socket.on( 'subscribe', function( userID ) {
        clients[userID] = socket.id;
    });

    socket.on( 'notifyMsg', function( data ) {
        var obj = JSON.parse( data );
        for( var i=0; i<obj.info.notifyUserIDs.length; i++ ) {
            var to = clients[obj.info.notifyUserIDs[i]];
            if( to ) {
                // Doesn't work
                io.sockets.socket(to).emit( 'notification', data );

                // Works
                //io.sockets.socket(to).broadcast.emit( 'notification', data );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about storing the sockets itself in the client hash and using it like this?

```
var app = express( );
var querystring = require('querystring');
var server  = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var clients = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function( socket ) {
    socket.on( 'subscribe', function( userID ) {
        clients[userID] = socket;
    });

    socket.on( 'notifyMsg', function( data ) {
        var obj = JSON.parse( data );
        for( var i=0; i<obj.info.notifyUserIDs.length; i++ ) {
            var to = clients[obj.info.notifyUserIDs[i]];
            if( to ) {
                to.emit( 'notification', data );
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi I've tried that too but emit just doesn't fires at all. I also try to console.log(to)  and I get the object output { id: 'BErkIOeBJP2lsU2OMJxn',
  namespace:
   { manager:
      { server: [Object],
        namespaces: [Object],
        sockets: [Circular],
        _events: [Object],
        settings: [Object],
        handshaken: [Object],
        connected: [Object],
        open: [Object],
        closed: {},
        rooms: [Object],
        roomClients: [Object],
        oldListeners: [Object],
        sequenceNumber: 1714461803,
        gc: [Object] },

Comment: This looks good for me. can you sniff the communication on wire? I mean the socket looks fine so probably it sends something to somewhere.

Comment: Sorry how to sniff on wire? Is it possible for you to test it on your side please? My client side is only socket.on('notification', function( res ) {
    console.log("browser = " + res)
});

Comment: I mean on server side. With ngrep for example.

Comment: Sadly I'm using windows here :(

Comment: wireshark maybe? Not 100% sure but it is a network sniffer for win